# JSON encoding; understanding JSON.stringify(s).indexOf(s)?

Tags: javascript, json, character-encoding

Consider the following function to determine if a character is "weird" or not. We'll consider characters that don't `JSON.stringify` with integrity to be "weird":

```
let isCharWeird = (char) => {
  return JSON.stringify(char).indexOf(char) === -1;
};
```

We can call this function over a whole range of characters to determine which characters are "weird" and which characters are not. If we call it over a huge range of characters (e.g. all the char codes from `0` to `1,000,000`), we can keep track of the ranges of purely weird characters, and the ranges of nice normal characters:

```js
let isCharWeird = (char) => {
  return JSON.stringify(char).indexOf(char) === -1;
};

let weirdRanges = [];
let normalRanges = [];
let weird = true; // Track if the current range is weird/normal
let startInd = 0; // Beginning index of current range
let range = 1000000; // How many chars to try
for (let i = 0; i < range; i++) {
  let nextWeird = isCharWeird(String.fromCharCode(i));
  
  // If the weirdness hasn't changed, skip. Don't skip the final range.
  if (nextWeird === weird && i !== range - 1) continue;
  
  if (i !== startInd)
    (weird ? weirdRanges : normalRanges).push(`: ${startInd} : ${i - 1} (${i - startInd} chars})`);
  
  startInd = i;
  weird = nextWeird;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify({ weirdRanges, normalRanges }, null, 2));
```

Try running that, the output is interesting!

**My question is:** why doesn't JSON seem to have integrity when representing the 1st 32 characters of every batch of 65536 characters?

Comment: consider ... `String.fromCharCode(1) === String.fromCharCode(65537)` now, what does that say about your "pattern" ... or the output of `for(i = 0; i < 65536; i++) if (String.fromCharCode(i) !== String.fromCharCode(i+65536)) console.log(i)` - i.e. none

Comment: then, when you look at [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) you'll see that the arguments for fromCharCode accept a range that is between 0 and 65535 - so, your pattern is now clear

Comment: Aha, simple answer to a stupid question! Should have checked that right away. Although I guess I would have expected `String.fromCharCode` to complain about exceeding the range...

If you write an answer I'll give ya the check!